About checksum calculation in bank treminal transaction protocol TITP
We are implementing a bank treminal transaction protocol TITP on POS device to directly card processing server.
TITP stand for Tranzware Iso Terminal Protocol. And our connection is raw socket.
From card processing team, they give us following example data to check the message:
String mac1 =  "2C76 BAE5 629E 0BC7 1901 C446 6276 3E23"; //D5CE40
String mac2 =  "10CE 3483 A716 34B3 683E 7F40 5EF8 4C6E"; //9790F6
String zone1 = "DAEF BA8F 150E BA3B ADOE 6883 EC62 7934"; //4D682B
String zone2 = "68B6 EC97 F2F7 B302 E0F7 2913 B90B B05E"; //D3CD0D
String pin1 =  "942F 62E5 86F8 4A8F 2CE9 075D 25AE B543"; //5981BB
String pin2 =  "C8B9 FDFE 4FCB DF31 5D1C 4F8F A194 2C3D"; //39715E

How to calculate those 6-Hex numbers from those 32-Hex numbers?
Any idea and advise will be really appreciated.
Thank you.
